# Where can I find common circuitry implementations of different computer system components?

Tags: integrated-circuit, computer-architecture

Mostly out of interest, I'm trying to understand common circuit-level implementations of computer components. I understand that implementations may differ widely, but I'd like to see examples. It would be great to see a lot of this stuff in one place, if such a website (or book) exists. Here's a list of the kind of components I'm trying to understand:

- RAM
- Flash memory
- Data + Address buses
- HDD's
- NVRAM
- ALUs
- Any processors, relatively simplistic ICs
- etc...

Here's a good example of the kind of thing I'm talking about:
http://www.righto.com/2014/10/how-z80s-registers-are-implemented-down.html

About 2/3's into the article, a circuit diagram is given that shows the register implementation.

It would be cool to see some of everything, to the point where one could have enough knowledge and resources to conceptually build (almost) an entire computer in their mind out of fundamental circuit components.

Does anyone know of such a resource?

Comment: "The TTL Data Book" from Texas Instruments. If you can still find a copy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the home built CPUs webring of sites?  This one covers a lot of what you are looking for:
http://cpuville.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can find [here](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/secondPage.html) a very well explained CPU made of relays for example.

You can search on youtube for ["computer transistor"](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=computer+transistor) for example to found computers made and explained at the transistor level.